# XHR request shows canceled status in Chrome (not CORS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I make an XHR Post request in Chrome and it immediately returns with an response with a type of error with no detail info.  In Chrome the response status shows up as "canceled".  However the request actually reaches the server and is processed by the server (verified with a breakpoint).  But the XHR error response and Chrome response status of "canceled" occurs before the request reaches the server.  I'm testing using a local webserver and app server with a single origin of "local.mydomain.com".  So there is no cross-domain implications.  What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Usually caused by leaving the page immediately after triggering the request.

Comment: I'm not leaving the page at any point when this XHR POST request is made.